# What are the current options for a Sharepoint Online trial from Windows XP?

Tags: 2010, development, sharepoint-online, administration, office-365

A year ago I had 30-day trial for Office 365 (Sharepoint Online 2010). Everything worked fine from  my Windows XP SP3 (x86. 32-bit) for development from Infopath Developer and Sharepoint Designer against Sharepoint Online which om Sharepoint Server 2010 at that time.

Recently I was  trying (at different days) to subscribe for another trial but after configuring my trial xxxx@yyyy.onmicrosoft.com account I could not create a Sharepoint site collection from it (_https://zzzz.microsoftOnline.com) repeating to get:

- "That didn't work We're sorry, but xxx@yyyy.onmicrosoft.com can't be found in the yyy-admin.sharepoint.com directory. Please try again later, while we try to automatically fix this for you"
- "Sorry, but your configuration is not supported

  Please re-start your session on a Windows 7 - Windows Server 2008 R2 machine using Internet Explorer 9
  download Internet Explorer here"

I've uses Internet Explorer 7 and latest versions of Google Chrome, Moozilla Firefox, Opera. It is known that it is impossible to install IE9 on Windows XP

I understood that the core problem is currently Sharepoint Online is on Sharepoint Server 2013 which is impossible to administer and develop from Windows XP as it was, without problems in case of Sharepoint 2010 Online, just a half year ago.

I tried to search for a free trial of Sharepoint, **specifically 2010**, Online.  Found and subscribed at http://www.mosexperts.com/free-trial.htm  but could not get anywhere getting:

- "The subscription in your quote is no longer available. For updated information about subscribing to Microsoft Online Services, contact your partner: 
  SmithBridge Technology Group 
  WILMINGTON, Delaware. http://www.microsoft.com/solutionfinder/marketplace/PartnerDetails.aspx?partnerId=bb06b865-8cd3-46db-81a9-61848ac59a58 Partner ID: 630002 "
- "Servers busy. Try again later.
  Internal services error occured. Please try again later"

Do I have any chances of trying Sharepoint Online from Windows XP SP3?
Are there Sharepoint 2010 Online?
What are they?

Comment: Hmmm... you could try cloudshare. http://www.cloudshare.com/solutions/development-and-testing/solutionsforsharepoint

Comment: Have you requested support from the O365 Team?  SharePoint is not dependent on OS, but the browser and Office client (there are some changes based on OS behavior, but if you have a supported client and office installation you are clear to use the service).  Note:  Windows XP is supported but Only IE8+ for certain functions that use ActiveX controls.  Windows XP with latest version of Chrome / Firefox is a supported config - I would see what support says.

Answer (score 1):

http://bit.ly/FreeOffice365Trial - try that link. It'll give you O365 E3 trial, along with SharePoint. It is for SharePoint 2013, though... If you need 2010, use cloudshare.com, as suggested in an earlier reply. I've used cloudshare, and it's a fantastic service for test/dev environments...